# How to boot from toshiba recovery partition after installing ubuntu 14.04.1?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows-7, data-recovery

Im new here and have not found a post even close to this so here it is:

i installed ubuntu 14.04.1 over my Windows 7 Home Premium installation. didn't loose any important data.skip to when the install is done

i tried out ubuntu and got sick of it after a while.(the try ubuntu option was greyed out)
i got sick of ubuntu after about an hour and i tried to boot into my recovery partition.

That's where im running into trouble: you are supposed to hold down the numerical "0" while turning on the power. but it just proceeds to load grub/ubuntu and does not even try to boot into the recovery partition. "000000000000" is all i get from holding it down

I know the recovery partition is intact,but i cant access it,even when setting a boot flag on it. i am stumped and i really need answers

thanks in advance!

specs

Toshiba satellite l775
intel core i3 dual core processor
original os:windows 7 home premium 64 bit sp1
let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 0):

You can not recover Windows if you installed Ubuntu instead of it, you need a working windows partition to restore the recovery data.

All the recovery partition does is use a earlier working version of Windows to fix any errors with the current install.

Your Windows is gone